# What special meaning does “#” have within a parameter-expansion pattern?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Suppose I’ve defined a variable like

```
number=123#456
```

and I want to print it without the leading “123#”. (This kind of thing happens in zsh when you’re working with numbers in bases other than 10.) The [“Parameter Expansion”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) section of the manual says,

> `${name#pattern}`
>
> `${name##pattern}`
>
> If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of *name*, then substitute the value of *name* with the matched portion deleted; otherwise, just substitute the value of *name*. In the first form, the smallest matching pattern is preferred; in the second form, the largest matching pattern is preferred.

This suggests to me that I should be able to say

```
print ${number#123#}
```

to get rid of the “123#”, but this actually outputs “3#456”. I found that I can get the desired effect if I escape the “#” that I’m trying to remove:

```
print ${number#123\#}    # prints "456"
```

What was the special meaning that the “#” had before I escaped it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with default settings in `zsh` 5.5.1 on OpenBSD.

Comment: Oh, hmm. Trying `zsh -c 'number=123#456; print ${number#123#}'` does give me just `456`, so I must have changed some setting that affects this. Let me look into it.

Comment: I’m not sure why, but it turns out that I did have `extended_glob` set, as implied by @Gilles’s answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#` is a [glob operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) that means “zero or more occurrences of the preceding character or parenthesized group”. It's the zsh way of writing the `*` regex operator. Hence `123#` matches `12` at the start of `123#456` when taking the shortest match (`${number#123#}`) and it matches `123` when taking the longest match (`${number##123#}`).

The `#` operator is only active when the [`extended_glob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-EXTENDED_005fGLOB) option is set. This option is not set by default, but it's common to set it in your configuration (because it's pretty useful and largely non-annoying), and it's always set while executing completion functions.